# How to change the default folder "static" in web.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

One of the libraries my project requires that a folder with the CSS files that were in the application root called "themes". web.py by default, uses the folder "static" to return the static file and just rename her... not One of the solutions I found online was the following

in urls it is necessary to add the line

```
'/(?:img|js|css)/.*',  'app.controllers.public.public',
```

in **app.controllers.public**

require nex code

```
class public:
    def GET(self): 
        public_dir = 'themes'
        try:
            file_name = web.ctx.path.split('/')[-1]
            web.header('Content-type', mime_type(file_name))
            return open(public_dir + web.ctx.path, 'rb').read()
        except IOError:
            raise web.notfound()

def mime_type(filename):
    return mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
```

but this solution does not work and files are still picked up from static...

is there a simple and clear solution to the problem? maybe we should change the name of the folder inside the web.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way to change web.py's use of `/static/`, but there is a really easy way to add one of your own, with no need to add anything to your list of `urls`.

Look at web.py's code and you'll find `web.httpserver.StaticMiddleware` is where this is defined. Your job, create another WSGI middleware, with the new prefix. Then, because this is WSGI middleware, add your new class to the run chain.

```
from web.httpserver import StaticMiddleware

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run(lambda app: StaticMiddleware(app, '/themes/')
```

If that was too terse for you, consider it's the same as explicitly creating a new subclass and passing that subclass to `app.run()`:

```
from web.httpserver import StaticMiddleware

class MyStaticMiddleware(StaticMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, app, prefix='/themes/'):
        StaticMiddleware.__init__(self, app, prefix)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run(MyStaticMiddleware)
```

Note that '/static/' will still work, loading files from the /static/ subdirectory: All you've done is added **another** processor, which does the same thing, but from the '/themes/' subdirectory.